# Set Renderbuffer Width and Height (Open GL ES)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm currently experiencing an issue with an Open GL ES renderbuffer where the backing and width are are both set to 15. Is there any way to set them to the width of 320 and 480?
My project is built up on Apple's EAGLView class and ES1Renderer, but I've moved it from the app delegate to a controller. I also moved the CADisplayLink outside of it (I update my game logic with the timestamp from this)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I add the glview to the window as follows:

```
   CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
   [window addSubview:gameController.glview];
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I synthesize the controller and the glview within it. The EAGLView and Renderer are otherwise unmodified.

Renderer Initialization:

```
  // Get the layer
    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

    eaglLayer.opaque = TRUE;
    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

    renderer =  [[ES1Renderer alloc] init];
```

Render "resize from layer" Method

```
- (BOOL)resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer
{   
    // Allocate color buffer backing based on the current layer size
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:layer];
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

   NSLog(@"Backing Width:%i and Height: %i", backingWidth, backingHeight);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you call renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:, what is layer.bounds?  The pixel width and height of your renderbuffer are allocated to match layer.bounds.size.

Comment: For whatever reason, the values for the layer.bounds CGRect are:
 -Origin: (50, 1650) | Size: w:30, h:1675

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right path. I got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's Documentation itself. Worked perfectly for me :

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot:(UIView*)eaglview {
    GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;
// Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
// If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point, 
// this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
// Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _colorRenderbuffer);

// Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

// Read pixel data from the framebuffer
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

// Create a CGImage with the pixel data
// If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
// otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

// OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
// Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
    // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
    CGFloat scale = eaglview.contentScaleFactor;
    widthInPoints = width / scale;
    heightInPoints = height / scale;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
}
else {
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    widthInPoints = width;
    heightInPoints = height;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
}

CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
// Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

// Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Clean up
free(data);
CFRelease(ref);
CFRelease(colorspace);
CGImageRelease(iref);

return image;
}
```